# Gatling DSL methods - substring available?

Tags: scala, gatling

I want to use the function substring with Gatling EL notation `${attributeName}` syntax. I am trying to do "${attributeName.substring(0,5)}". It doesn't work.

I'm getting the error `No attribute named '0,5' is defined`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Gatling EL placeholders like `${xxx}` are not variables, those are just parts of string that are replaced with session attribute value on simulation execution (not on compilation). What you are looking for are session expressions and session API: 
[Expressions](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/session/expression_el/#expression)
[Session API](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/session/session_api/)

Example code would look like that:

```
session => session("attributeName").as[String].substring(0,5)
```